# Set column admin grid become the first one to be sorted

Tags: magento2, grid, sort

I have a column in my custom admin grid like this:

```
<column name="delivery_date_to" class="Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Date" component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/date">
            <settings>
                <filter>dateRange</filter>
                <dataType>date</dataType>
                <label translate="true">ETA To</label>
                <sorting>desc</sorting>
            </settings>
        </column>
```

i'd like this column to be sorted first, so it will look like this when everytime i load the grid:

[image]

Comment: <sorting>asc</sorting> only use in 1 column which you have want to sort.

Answer (score 0):

Customize your data source $collection of grid like so.

```
public function getCollection()
{
    $collection =  parent::getCollection();
    $collection->setOrder('delivery_date_to', 'DESC');
    return $collection;
}
```

Comment: i've tried that and i don't want to be sorted from the collection, but i want it to be sorted manually at the frontend grid, just like the image